# How do I get next element from list after search string match in python

Tags: python

Hi Friends I have a list where I'm searching for string and along with searched string I want to get next element of list item. Below is sample code

```
>>> contents = ['apple','fruit','vegi','leafy']
>>> info = [data for data in contents if 'fruit' in data]
>>> print(info)
['fruit']
```

I want to have output as
fruit
vegi

Comment: *Aside*: The use of `'fruit' in data` in your example matches any string that contains the word `fruit` in it. So it would match "fruity" and "passion fruit" also. Or did you mean `'fruit' == data`?

Comment: I'm looking for exact match fruit

Answer (score 6):

What about:

```
def find_adjacents(value, items):
    i = items.index(value)
    return items[i:i+2]
```

You'll get a `ValueError` exception for free if the `value` is not in `items` :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to iterate over the list zipped with itself.

Calling `zip(contents, contents[1:])`, allows the `data` variable to take on these values during the loop:

```
('apple', 'fruit')
('fruit', 'vegi')
('vegi', 'leafy')
```

in that order. Thus, when "fruit" is matched, `data` has the value `('fruit', 'vegi')`.

Consider this program:

```
contents = ['apple','fruit','vegi','leafy']
info = [data for data in zip(contents,contents[1:]) if 'fruit' == data[0]]
print(info)
```

We compare "fruit" to `data[0]`, which will match when `data` is `('fruit', 'vegi')`.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me why you are keeping data[0]? Will this be stored as tuple?

Answer (score 1):

I might think of itertools...

```
>>> import itertools
>>> contents = ['apple','fruit','vegi','leafy']
>>> icontents = iter(contents)
>>> iterable = itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: 'fruit' not in x, icontents)
>>> next(iterable)
'fruit'
>>> next(iterable)
'vegi'
```

Note that if you really know that you have an exact match (e.g. `'fruit' == data` instead of `'fruit' in data`), this becomes easier:

```
>>> ix = contents.index('fruit')
>>> contents[ix: ix+2]
['fruit', 'vegi']
```

In both of these cases, you'll need to specify what should happen if no matching element is found.

Answer (score 1):

This straightforward imperative approach worked for me:

```
contents = ['apple', 'fruit', 'vegi', 'leafy']
result = '<no match or no successor>'
search_term = 'fruit'
for i in range(len(contents)-1):
   if contents[i] == search_term:
       result = contents[i+1]
print result
```

Note that you don't specify what the behavior should be for 1) not finding the search term, or 2) finding a match at the end of the list.