# Select next element from list conditionally

Tags: python, list, select, element

Beginner's question:

Say I have the following list,

```
list=['spam', 'eggs', 'ham', 'foo', 'bar']
```

I want to check if a certain item is in the list. If this item is in the list, I want to select the next item. E.g. if `eggs` is in `list`, I want to return `ham`.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898751/how-do-i-get-next-element-from-list-after-search-string-match-in-python), but I do *not* want to specify the next element. I.e. I want the code to return the next item based on the position of the initial element.

Something like,

```
if 'eggs' in list:
     next = item(position of eggs + 1)
```

How do I go about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that there's only 1 item with same value (else `index` doesn't work as expected since it returns the index of the *first* occurrence) you could do this:

```
l=['spam', 'eggs', 'ham', 'foo', 'bar']

try:
    next_element = l[l.index('eggs')+1]
except (ValueError,IndexError):
    next_element = ""

print(next_element)
```

if element not found or comes last, the exception is trapped and nothing is printed.

BTW: I changed the `list` and `next` names because they're built-ins.